# How to add to object[] in loop?

Tags: c#

EDIT: original question did not make sense so hopefully this one does.

How to make the following object below

```
object[] parms = { "p1", 1, "p2", 2, "p3", 3,..., "pn", n };
```

Obviously this is not working:

```
foreach (var id in ids)
{
    objects[] parms = { "p" + id.ToString(), id };       
}
```

Comment: `someFunction("", parms.ToArray());`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What is `actual {p#'s, #'s}`?

Comment: well inspector shows that parms[0] is object[2], but I want parms[0] to show {p1, 1}.

Comment: @O.O And that *is* an array of size two, so it is exactly what you want.

Comment: @O.O Then instead of passing in an array of arrays, pass in an array of something that has a `ToString` implementation that does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question has been changed....

You can construct your object array like:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; //assuming your ids are like that
List<object> objList = new List<object>();
foreach (var item in ids)
{
    objList.Add("p" + item);
    objList.Add(item);
}

object[] parms = objList.ToArray();
```

now parms would contain multiple objects, first a string with `"p" + id` and the second as `id`.

Not really sure why you need such construct, you can use `Dictionary<int,string>` or a `List` of your custom object with a property for string and another for int `id`.

---

Old Answer.

Just call it like:

```
List<object> parms = new List<object>();
someFunction("somestring", parms.ToArray());
```

See: [params (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

> You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified
>   in the parameter declaration **or an array of arguments of the
>   specified type**.

You can also do:

```
someFunction("string", ids.Select(r => "p" + r).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert the list to an array.

```
someFunction("", parms.toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct in their instruction of how to use params.

But in your case, you're double-nesting your object arrays.

Your `params[0]` is an `object[2]` - presumably because there were two `id in ids`, and because you're adding each "thing made out of an ID" as an `object[]`.

So `params[0][0]` is your first id's pID string, and `params[0][1]` is its numeric `id`.

To make this cleaner, you could define your own class to hold the information, or use Tuple<>. Then, inspect the contents of your params[] - which should be of this type, and you can cast them and use them as such.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change it like this:

```
someFunction( string a, IList parms)
{
  // this should receive array of actual {p#'s, #'s}
}
```

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. You can't be sure. He was asking how to pass a collection to something that only takes an array, though, so this is currently wrong. However, C#6 may be introducing params IEnumerable<T>, which would be wonderful.